# Can't replicate a POST request

Tags: python, python-requests, session-cookies, request-headers

There is this website: https://www.lyxoretf.co.uk/en/instit/products/search, and I am trying to form the correct Python POST request to be able to download the excel file and save it locally.

You can download the file by clicking on the icon to the right of the rows count dropdown at the top of the table. Recording the network activity (and copying the cURL request) I find that the headers that I need to set, as well as the form data (to get all of the columns in the table):

```
HEADERS = {
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Pragma': 'no-cache',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    'Origin': 'https://www.lyxoretf.co.uk',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36',
    'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
    'Referer': 'https://www.lyxoretf.co.uk/en/instit/products/search',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
}

FORM_DATA = "tabViewForm=tabViewForm&tabViewForm%3AtabView%3Aoptions5_focus=&tabViewForm%3AtabView%3Aoptions5_input=&tabViewForm%3AtabView%3Aoptions6_focus=&tabViewForm%3AtabView%3Aoptions6_input=&tabViewForm%3AtabView%3Aoptions7_focus=&tabViewForm%3AtabView%3Aoptions7_input=&tabViewForm%3AtabView%3Aoptions8_focus=&tabViewForm%3AtabView%3Aoptions8_input=&tabViewForm%3AtabView%3AcolumnsId_focus=&tabViewForm%3AtabView%3AcolumnsId=ETF+Name&tabViewForm%3AtabView%3AcolumnsId=Ticker&tabViewForm%3AtabView%3AcolumnsId=ISIN&tabViewForm%3AtabView%3AcolumnsId=Trading+Ccy&tabViewForm%3AtabView%3AcolumnsId=TER&tabViewForm%3AtabView%3AcolumnsId=AUM&tabViewForm%3AtabView%3AcolumnsId=Dividend+Treatment&tabViewForm%3AtabView%3AcolumnsId=Inception+Date&tabViewForm%3AtabView%3AcolumnsId=Fund+Type&tabViewForm%3AtabView%3AcolumnsId=Replication+Method&tabViewForm%3AtabView%3AcolumnsId=NAV&tabViewForm%3AtabView%3AcolumnsId=1Y&tabViewForm%3AtabView%3AcolumnsId=3Y&tabViewForm%3AtabView%3AcolumnsId=5Y&tabViewForm%3AtabView%3AcolumnsId=Index+Ticker&tabViewForm%3AtabView%3AcolumnsId=Factsheets&tabViewForm%3AtabView%3AcolumnsId=KIID&tabViewForm%3AtabView%3AcolumnsId=Prospectus&tabViewForm%3AtabView%3AcolumnsId=Mnemo&tabViewForm%3AtabView%3AcolumnsId=Tax+data+%28PEA%29&tabViewForm%3AtabView%3AshareDatatable_rppDD=10&tabViewForm%3AtabView_activeIndex=0&tabViewForm%3AtabView_scrollState=0&javax.faces.ViewState=-5754685498185340066%3A-4854945738216683285&tabViewForm%3AtabView%3AexportToXlsShare=tabViewForm%3AtabView%3AexportToXlsShare"
```

I then get the cookie by doing the following:

```
response = session.get('https://www.lyxoretf.co.uk/en/instit/products/search')
cookie = session.cookies.get_dict()
cookie_string = "; ".join([str(x)+"="+str(y) for x,y in cookie.items()])
```

now ready to make a post request:

```
HEADERS["Cookie"] = cookie_string
r = requests.post(
    "https://www.lyxoretf.co.uk/en/instit/products-pretty/search-pretty",
    data=FORM_DATA,
    headers=HEADERS,
)
```

but `r.content` turns out to be `b""`, and the status code is `200`. I can see that the response headers are incorrect too. What am I missing?

Comment: just an idea that I had, which may have no validity at all is to make a request from the session, rather than `requests.get`

Comment: I tried `session.post(...)`, but with no luck. But I agree that you probably don't need to rewrite cookies to separate request (`Session` object does it for you). Unless you really want a completely separate connection.

Comment: looks like when you make an initial request there are a bunch of requests in the background that set the cookies, that aren't set when I do it through the session. I gave up, and just wrote a Selenium bot for now

Comment: using session everywhere does not fix anything, though